# user cancellation not being caught by TRY CATCH

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, try-catch, cancellation

I'm having trouble in MSSMS 2012, my SQL SCRIPT may be cancelled by the user, I've made a TRY CATCH block to log into a table any error event (including user cancellation) but user cancellations are not being logged (so I don't think its getting into the CATCH block)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

BEGIN TRY
    
    --INSERT FOR LOGGING THE TRANSACTION

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    --CODE CANCELLED BY USER

    --UPDATE FOR LOGGING THE TRANSACTION'S SUCCESS

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE
    @V_ERROR_NUM INT = ERROR_NUMBER(),
    @V_ERROR_MSG VARCHAR(1000)=ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
    @V_ERROR_SEVERITY VARCHAR(100)=ERROR_SEVERITY(), 
    @V_ERROR_STATE VARCHAR(10)=ERROR_STATE()


    --UPDATE FOR LOGGING THE TRANSACTION'S ERROR


    RAISERROR(@V_ERROR_MSG,@V_ERROR_SEVERITY,@V_ERROR_STATE);
END CATCH

SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
```

TLDR: the Update into the custom LOG table I made is never executed on a user cancel.

Instead of getting "45188" as error number, and "The operation has been cancelled by user." as error text. Both columns have NULLs even though the UPDATE command should change them.

Thank you guys!

Comment: If a user cancels a script then the entire batch is cancelled, so no, your `CATCH` won't be entered; the batch was completely aborted.

Comment: You can't protect against cancellation, and why would you? You could move both clauses inside the transaction, at least in that case you get both or nothing (on rollback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cancellation request comes through to the server as an `ATTENTION` TDS packet. This is not catchable in user code, and will result in immediate batch termination.

If you want to log such errors, as well as other severe uncatchable errors, log them on the client-side.

To ensure rollbacks happen correctly in such cases, always have `XACT_ABORT ON` (as you have done).

Do not use `RAISERROR` as it does not re-raise an existing error correctly. Instead use `THROW;` to rethrow an error (and make *sure* you terminate the previous statement with `;`).